# caffe.io.Transformer to use for LeNet classification

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to classify digits (0-9), using LeNet.

I read images of dimension 28x28, transpose them, and send one color channel into the net.

```
bild = mpimg.imread('pathToImg')
bild = np.transpose(bild,(2,0,1))
```

And get predictions that make no sense whatsoever.
I see that PyCaffe has a Transformer that gets this job done but I don't know how I would use it for LeNet.

---

I am using the net from caffe/examples/mnist (hopefully that answers what sort of data the net expects).

The only thing that's different is that the input is now:

```
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 1
  dim: 28
  dim: 28
}
```

Comment: what input your net expects? `float32` in range [0..255], range [0..1]? does your net subtract the mean of the image? why don't you convert to gray? how were the inputs processed during net's training?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are directly using the deploy prototxt, you should take a look at the "data" layer in lenet_train_test.prototxt (or a file with a similar name) which will give you an indication of how data is preprocessed.

By looking at the files I have, it seems that the LeNet example performs scaling of all input data. This is indicated by the following lines in "data" layer

```
transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
}
```

So that's one thing you might be missing. Have a look at [imagenet tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb) for pointers on preprocessing (esp Transformer). Second, you are reading in the image as

```
bild = np.transpose(bild,(2,0,1))
```

This looks like an error based on the channel swaps you are performing, so make sure that the data sent to the network has the dimensions - 1 (batch size) x 1 (channels) x 28(height) x 28(width).